# Debugging Java Meal Price Calculator

Tags: java

I am having some issues debugging this code and was hoping you all would be able to assist.

If you take a look near the end of the `main` method, you will find `int partySplit.split.nextInt()` which reads from `Scanner split = new Scanner(System.in);`. The first problem is that the program seems to be skipping over this. Why is it skipping this set of code?

The second issue is that it then prints out the "Total meal price is $128" but I have removed `System.out.println("Total meal price is $" + groupTotalMealPrice);` I have also rebuilt the program (using IntelliJ) to see if it was simply a compile issue. I have also copy and pasted into a new class file and I get the same results.

What I would like to see is it ask the party size and then not only print out the total, but also the total for each depending on the split. I also would like to see the text that I removed to actually go away.

Any assistance with this would be great.

Code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MealPriceCalculator {

    //note 'double' in 'public static double' is the return type.
    //notice that is has been changed from 'void' which means return nothing.
    //when this is changed, we will need to denote a return value.
    //in this case, we are returning the result to the main method.
    //when returning a variable, you are making it accessible in another method.
    public static double calculateTotalMealPrice(double listedMealPrice,
                                               double tipRate,
                                               double taxRate) {
        double tip = (tipRate * listedMealPrice) / 100;
        double tax = (taxRate * listedMealPrice) / 100;
        double result = listedMealPrice + tip + tax;

        return result;

    }

    //note 'void' in 'public static void' is the return type.
    //this means that nothing is returned.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner mealPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner tip = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner tax = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner split = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the meal price (excluding $):");
        double listedMealPrice = mealPrice.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("You entered $" + listedMealPrice + " as the cost of your meal.");

        System.out.println("Please enter the tip percentage (excluding %)");
        double tipRate = tip.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("You entered " + tipRate + "% as the percentage you wish to tip.");

        System.out.println("Please enter the tax rate (excluding the %):");
        double taxRate = tax.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("You entered " + taxRate + "% as the tax rate.");

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of people that will be splitting the bill.");
        int partySplit = split.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered " + partySplit + " as the number of people you will be" +
                "splitting the bill with.");


        double groupTotalMealPrice = calculateTotalMealPrice(listedMealPrice, tipRate, taxRate);
        System.out.println(groupTotalMealPrice);

        double individualMealPrice = groupTotalMealPrice / partySplit;
        System.out.println(individualMealPrice);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Please enter the meal price (exluding $):
100
You entered $100.0 as the cost of your meal.
Please enter the tip percentage (excluding %)
20
You entered 20.0% as the percentage you wish to tip.
Please enter the tax rate (excluding the %):
8
You entered 8.0% as the tax rate.
Your total meal price is $128.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Sounds like you're running an older version of your code.  I've never used intelliJ myself, but I'd suggest deleting the compiled files pertaining to your project and try running it again to guarantee you're not stuck on old code.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that would have resolved itself when I copy and pasted the code into a new class file with a different name. I wonder why doing that still resulted in the previous results. However, following your advice it now works.

Comment: Make sure you right click on that file and select run !

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using each Scanner object for each input, You can use one object to get all the inputs

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

double listedMealPrice = sc.nextDouble();
double tipRate = sc.nextDouble();
double taxRate = sc.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. That is good to know. I also assume that it would work with multiple data types? Ie: nextDouble(), nextInt(),... under one declaration?

Comment: Yeah it will work for multiple data types too!